# “loading” spinner not leaving the TTTableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, three20

I had a TTTableViewController used in iPad and initially I want it to be empty. When it first loads it actually calls:

```
- (id)initWithNavigatorURL:(NSURL*)URL query:(NSDictionary*)query {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.dataSource = nil;
    }
    return self;
}
```

However, the "loading" spinner stays in there and won't go away.
Why is this? I thought that this could happen because init wasn't called, but indeed it is.
I need some help.

Answer (score 1):

When a `TTTableViewController` is presented on screen, it accesses it's model. If there's no model set, like in your case it creates a model in `[TTModelViewController createInterstitialModel]`. By default this will be a TTModel (the class not the protocol), which in turn does nothing then appearing to be loading.

In your `createModel` implementation you would need to create a model that does what you want and assign that to self.model.

Also note, that creating dataSources and / or model in the initializer is not optimal, consider creating your dataSources / models in `createModel`. They will be created only when needed (when the view appears on screen).

Comment: what if I just want it to be empty?